# Polymer/Dart Input with autocomplete

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

Would you like an "input" with "search" in Dart preferably using Polymer. For example, something similar to the "input" and "search" of the Google Maps (www.maps.google.com).

When you type in "input", a list of options is presented, related to what is being typed, in which you can select the desired option.

What would be a simple way (or example) to implement this behavior in Polymer / Dart?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't even need Polymer for this

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_datalist.asp

You can generate the `<datalist>` by binding to a collection of values in Polymer.

**UPDATE**

```dart
<link rel="import" href="../../packages/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="../../packages/paper_elements/paper_input.html">
<polymer-element name="app-element">
  <template>
    <style>
      :host {
        display: block;
      }
    </style>
    <paper-input id="pi"></paper-input>
    <datalist id="dl">
      <option>abc</option>
      <option>abcd</option>
      <option>bcd</option>
      <option>bcde</option>
    </datalist>
  </template>
  <script type="application/dart" src="app_element.dart"></script>
</polymer-element>
```

```dart
import 'dart:html' as dom;
import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';

@CustomTag('app-element')

class AppElement extends PolymerElement {

  AppElement.created() : super.created() {
  }

  attached() {
    super.attached();
    var inp = $['pi'].querySelector('* /deep/ input') as dom.TextInputElement;
    inp.parentNode.append($['dl']); // seems to be only found when it is inside the same shadowRoot
    inp.attributes['list'] = 'dl';  // assign the id of the datalist to the 'list' attribute
  }
}
```

Comment: Okay, but I would like to use paper-input (or core-input) Polymer Component to get this behavior.

Comment: Seems this is work-in-progress https://github.com/Polymer/core-input/issues/27. The core-input (paper-input extends core-input) has an `<input>` internally. You could connect the input with the datalist programmatically. I guess it is not possible in markup currently.

Comment: My expectation for Polymers components was that they bring at least what is defined in HTML5 standard. 
For example, <... type = "search" ...> is a standard in HTML5, and my expectation is that it would also be in Polymer components. 
Apparently, you should consider the Polymer components as something "different" and "new" and not as something that extends the standard with new HTML5 features and behaviors! 
Thank you for your attention and Günter tips!

Comment: core-elements and paper-elements are still actively developed and in early stage. If you need a feature file an issue in the GitHub repo of the element. I'm sure they want to hear of your requirements.  
I guess you can also see these elements as an attempt to extend the possibilities for browser applications without going through the W3C standard committee. The basic technologies are standardized but not every new tag needs to be agreed on by a commitee. core- and paper-elements are a showcase, a foundation, ...